# ASP.NET MVC: Localization issues (wrong resx file for culture)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a `Strings.resx` and a `Strings.nl.resx` file.
The first contains a English string, the other a Dutch string. They are part of a `C# Class Library` project: `Module`.

```
 public static string testString()
 {          
      //I Force the culture to always be english
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
       Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
       return Strings.Hello;
 }
```

When I call them from a simple `Console Application`, it works:

```
  Console.WriteLine(Module.testString()); //English string gets returned
```

When I do the same from my `ASP.NET MVC` application, I get the Dutch version...

```
    public ActionResult testCulture()
    {
        return Content(Module.testString()); //Dutch string gets returned..?!
    }
```

I am using a Dutch Windows, so any auto-setting will be Dutch.But how can I get a different string when the culture is hardcoded to en-us in the class library??

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a Neutral Resources Language specified anywhere? If it is set to `"nl"` or `"nl-NL"`, any request for a resource that is not found will eventually end up fetching the `"nl"` resource. Since you do not have a `Strings.en-US.resx` or `Strings.en.resx`, setting `CurrentUICulture` to `"en-US"` would make the system use the neutral resources language.

Answer (score 0):

check if your web.config is not having a globalization tag having a language set to dutch

or

if you are using internet explorer, go to tools > internet options and click on language button, if it's showing dutch language before the english one, change it